# Merge-conflicts Automation

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, continuous-delivery

Using CI/CD approach, one of the principle mentioned, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172303/principles-of-continuous-delivery):

```
Automate wherever possible
```

---

Merging can be done two ways, based on the scenario:

1) Fast-forward merge

2) 3-way merge

---

Does it make sense to think about automating merge conflicts?

Comment: A *fast-forward* is not a merge, and cannot have conflicts.

Comment: @torek agreed. it was typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  A merge conflict is literally the end result of a *failure* to automate.

Remember:  Git is doing its *best* to ensure that it doesn't lose any data, and a merge conflict is Git telling you in its standard, paranoid fashion that it *could* lose data and it wants you to intervene.

Automating wherever possible is the right mentality.  Merge conflicts are *very* risky to automate, which would preclude the possibility of automating it at all.