# Git & ApartCI - How to verify code conflicts before inviting functional breakage?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, 3-way-merge

Following Trunk Based Development, shown below:

[image]

---

Assume there are two **short-lived** feature branches(`f1` and `f2`) created from `master`(trunk). For implementation, source code files used for these branches **overlap**, in this scenario.

Assume, there is one CI/CD pipeline for `master`(trunk) that gets triggered on code change.

---

One code conflict that can be possible is functional, `f1` could remove or modify existing source code that `f2` uses.... This is **not a VCS conflict**.

Developer1 has perform `git commit` on `f1`(in laptop) at time `t` and yet to `push`

Developer2 has perform `git commit` on `f2`(in laptop) at time `t+24` and yet to `push`

---

As per my understanding, below is the scenario in commit History file of laptop, before push:

[image]
Given above sccenario, `f1` can get merge with `master`, which is a simple **fast-forward merge**. So, `master` and `f1` will point to `156b4bf` commit snapshot, after this merge, as shown below:

[image]
CI/CD pipeline gets triggered, as merge is successful, with no conflicts

But when `f2` commit happens after 24 hours, Git will perform **3-way merge** using 3 snapshots(`156b4bf`, `96f5b29` and `c435356`), as shown below:

[image]
CI/CD pipeline gets triggered again, **if** merge is successful. My understanding is, Git should block 3-way merge due to functional conflict.

---

1) Using Git, Does fast-forward/3-way merge detect functional conflict?

2) If yes, are there any other non-VCS conflict scenarios that [ApartCI](https://angel.co/projects/555629-apartci) address? that Git cannot... if yes, how?

*Note: No plan to use [Gitflow workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)*

Comment: @DanCornilescu Firstly... For the scenario, given in query... does 3-way merge detect the non-VCS conflict?

Answer (score 1):

A **purely functional** conflict is one in which the 2 conflicting changes don't touch the same files:

- **f1** modifies a function prototype (let's say in file **S1**) and **all** its usages (let's say in files **S2** and **S3**)
- **f2** adds a **new** function usage in a different file in which the function wasn't used before (let's say in file **S4**), using the original prototype since it doesn't yet see the **f1** change

Each change takes in isolation could pass verifications, but when integrated together in the same branch the code won't work as the invocation added in  **S4** won't match the updated prototype from **S1**.

In such case both merges are fast-forward and the conflict can not be detected by git - there will be no actual file merges in the 3-way merge since the changesets don't touch the same files. Thus neither will the conflict be detected by git-based tools analyzing the merge, for example by gerrit.

Only the verifications performed by the CI/CD tool can detect such purely functional conflict by finding the mismatch. Depending on the language used it'd be either a build/compilation error or a test/runtime/execution error.

If the 2 changes cause a merge conflict (3-way or not) it means the conflict is a VCS one, not a purely functional one and yes, it would be detected by git and/or git-based tools, so it would need to be addressed before the merge is allowed (a CI/CD tool execution would not be *necessary* for detecting it)

To your 2nd question ApartCI would detect either kind of conflict:

- if it's a VCS conflict the 2 changes are overlapping (i.e. they both touch at least one common source file) so they won't be [bundled](https://apartci.apartsw.com/help_term.html#bundle) together for simultaneous verification. Which means that they will never end up in a [primary bundle](https://apartci.apartsw.com/help_term.html#primary_bundle) together. One of them will be committed and end up in the project's [baseline](https://apartci.apartsw.com/help_term.html#baseline) first. As soon as that happens the other change will fail patching in its next verification attempt and will be rejected.
- if it's a purely functional conflict the 2 changes are not overlapping, so they may or may not end up in the same bundle.

  - if they are not in the same bundle the flow of events will be pretty much the same as that for a VCS conflict
  - if they are in the same bundle the bundle verification will fail and following the [bundle splitting actions](https://apartci.apartsw.com/help_term.html#split) they will eventually end up in different bundle and again the same flow of events as that for a VCS conflict will follow

Comment: Dan is taking C language as example here... when he says... function prototype and definition...

Comment: For your point... "there will be no 3-way merge", am bit skeptic on this... 3-way merge happens after f2 commit. 3-way merge is not invoked based on same/different file strategy.. 3-way merge is invoked based on the path(direct/indirect) between master and f2(any branch that needs to be merged).

Comment: Sorry, by `there will be no 3-way merge` I mean that no files will be technically merged in such case, simply a different version of the files will be selected.

Comment: yes....  the criteria is... to **just detect** the conflict... I would not need a tool to resolve the conflict... Isn't it? Human intervention is better....

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223312/3317808) it says...Merge conflicts are very risky to automate, which would preclude the possibility of automating it at all..... is ApartCI trying to detect the conflict or detect&resolve the conflict?

Comment: Human intervention is better to **resolve** conflicts, yes, but to just **detect** them automation is IMHO preferable. Why waste developer time with something that the machine can typically do faster and better?

Comment: No, apartCI makes no attempt to resolve conflicts, its only goal is to isolate them as efficiently as possible and pass them to humans for resolution, while automatically driving the integration of the other, non-conflicting changes.