# Workaround for lack of wildcard auth options in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

We're using google Cloud Build to deploy pull-request specific versions of our app to GAE so we can share dev versions with stakeholders before launching them into the wild. On GAE, a url looks like `http://[VERSION_ID]-dot-[YOUR_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com` or `https://my-pr-name-dot-projectname.appspot.com`

We're want to allow for stakeholders to preview and to run E2E tests (including Firebase login) but because of what's essentially a wildcard subdomain, we'd have to manually whitelist each subdomain in the the Firebase control panel under "Authorized domains" after a deploy. Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't allow for wildcard style whitelisting (eg. *-dot-projectname.appspot.com).

We've reached out to Google support but they've confirmed that whitelisting can only be done manually.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use a separate, staging project for PR testing.

You'd use whitelisting for `http://[YOUR_STAGING_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com` or `https://staging_projectname.appspot.com`. And you'd manage your mapping from a specific PR to the staging project via traffic migrations, which can be done [programmatically](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/migrating-splitting-traffic) from your PR automation scripts.

The drawback would be that you'd effectively be verifying only one PR at a time. But that's not necessarily all bad: serializing PR verifications eliminates the risk of breakages due to [conflicting changes that each pass in isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271203/git-apartci-how-to-verify-code-conflicts-before-inviting-functional-breakage/54279964#54279964).

There are also advantages of using a separate project for testing purposes you might find of interest, see [Advantages of implementing CI/CD environments at GAE project/app level vs service/module level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218971/advantages-of-implementing-ci-cd-environments-at-gae-project-app-level-vs-servic)

Comment: This is definitely an option and one we had considered but I'm really interested in a solve for multi-versioned approach. Thanks for your note though!

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same issue and decided on authorizing a constant number (say N) of "preview environments". We use GCP cloud run and our CI/CD is ran by github actions. The idea is to iterate through the number of environments such that every N PRs we'll use the same environment, this is done by calculating the modulo of the PR number to N.

Here's the main bash command in the github actions yaml:

`run: echo "PREVIEW_ENV=$((${{github.event.number}} % ${{ env.N_PREVIEW_ENVS }}))" >> $GITHUB_ENV`